# How to put text from file into array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, unique

I need to read text from a file (text of few sentences) and then write down all unique characters. To do that I need to use an array. I wrote this code but it gives me nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i;
  FILE *in = fopen("test.txt", "r");

  if (in) {
    char mas[50];
    size_t n = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(in)) != EOF) {
      mas[n++] = (char)ch;
    }
    fclose(in);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    printf("%c", mas[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It actually should generate a compilation error indicating that `mas` is undefined at the `printf("%c",mas[i])` statement since `char mas[50]` is only defined inside your `if` statement block.

Comment: this one fixed. now it gives some output, but it's not understantable and it contains numbers only, not characters from text.

Comment: That is because you are printing all 50 elements of `mas`, but you might not be reading 50 characters from the file. The remaining `mas` entries are just random memory contents. You must keep track of how many characters you read, then only print that many out. For example, if you put your `size_t n` declaration outside of the `if` block, then you could use `n` as your count, and do `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)...` to print each read character.

Answer (score 1):

```
//low level input output commands method

#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i,n,v=1;
    char s[256],str;

    for (i=1;i<=255;i++)
        s[i]='0';
    x=open("out.txt",O_RDONLY);

    if (x==-1)
    {
        printf("Invalid file path");
        return 0;
    }

    while (n!=0)
    {
        n=read(x,&str,1);
        s[(int)str]='1';
        v=0;
    }
    close(x);

    for (i=1;i<=255;i++)
        if (s[i]=='1')
            printf("%c",(char)i);

    if (v)
        printf("Blank file!");
    close(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `str[1]`??? why don't you just do `char str;` and `read(x, &str, 1)` and you should use meaningful names for variables. also format your code so it's readable, trust me, you will never regret to do so.

Comment: Also, you should check for the return value of `open()` it returns `-1` on error, for example if the file does not exists, in that case you will try to read from an invalid file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with `scope`. `mas` was declared within your `if` block of code and has no visibility outside the `if` block. Move the declaration for `mas` outside the block. You need to keep `n` outside as well i.e.:

```
int i;
char mas[50];
size_t n = 0;
```

Next you fail to limit your read to `less than 50 chars` and will easily overflow `mas`. Add a check on `n`:

```
 while ((ch = getc(in)) != EOF && n < 50) {
```

Finally limit your write of characters to the number read `n`:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

That will compile and run. If you had compiled with **warnings** enabled, the compiler would have identified the `scope` problem for you. Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` at a minimum.

Comment: The compiler wouldn't compile that code without warnings, because `mas` was not defined outside the `if`.

Comment: That's what **If you had compiled with warnings enabled, the compiler would have identified the scope problem for you.** says. What part of that is unclear?

Comment: you don't need to enable warnings for that.

Comment: Is there something wrong with telling a new user to use warnings? The warning add the clue that **variable ‘mas’ set but not used**

Comment: NO, there is nothing wrong. I never compile without `-Wall -Werror` with `gcc`. It's just that the problem will not generate a warning but an error, inside the `if` it will be set but never used, but outside the if it's not even declared, so without warnings enabled the code will not compile and the compiler will throw the following error `error: 'mas' undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Answer (score -1):

If you intend to read some char's to your array and print out unique one's check the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,flag;
    char mas[50];
    size_t n = 0;
    FILE *in = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (in) {    

        int ch;
        while ((ch = getc(in)) != EOF && n < 50)  {
            mas[n++] = (char)ch;
        }
        fclose(in);
        }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)     
    {
      flag = 0;
      for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
      {
         if( mas[i] == mas[j])
         {
         flag = 1;
         break;
         }
      }
       if(!flag)
       {
         printf("%c\n",mas[i]);
        }
    }
      return 0;
}
```